dotnet jb cleanupcode introduces redundant type specification
I am struggling with dotnet jb cleanupcode changing
    UserEntity[] users = [
        new() {
            Name = "Example User 1",
        },
        new() {
            Name = "Example User 2",
        },
    ];

to
    UserEntity[] users = [
        new UserEntity {
            Name = "Example User 1",
        },
        new UserEntity {
            Name = "Example User 2",
        },
    ];

Both Rider and my CI in which I execute the same commands suggest me using the first variant. This means somewhere in my environment the rule that causes this, is configured inconsistently between CI/IDE and local environment.
I can't seem to find the correct rule for the redundant type specification though. Which rules could cause this (.editorconfig / roslyn etc.)?

You can set the new expression style in Rider as the following settings.
The corresponding ReSharper EditorConfig flag is resharper_arrange_object_creation_when_type_evident_highlighting

Have a check on this rule.
